# Designing large static Postgres database for quick index searching

Tags: postgresql, database-design

**Background info**

I'm sitting on 5000 files each consisting of 10 million lines and 15 columns. Each file `i` stores regression information for a given dependent variable `y_i` on an independent variable `id`. For a given file `i` the data looks like this:

```
id    beta    se    pvalue    ...etc
```

where column `id` represents the name of the dependent variable. Note: the `id` column is identical for all files, it is the value of the other columns that changes per file.

I regularly need to loop through each file, retrieve `m` lines and then merge them. To do this I either read the data into memory and manipulate it with R or I run an awk script. This is obviously slow so I took 100 files and put them into a Postgres (v12.11) database with two different designs:

1. Each file `i` for dependent variable `y_i` is its own table with a btree
   index on `id`.
2. One long (100 * 10 million) table with a btree index on `(id, dependent_var)`,
   where `dependent_var` is a new column with value `y_1` the first 10 million lines,
   `y_2` the next 10 million lines and so on.

I set up a simple simulation where I randomly draw `m` indexes and `k` dependent variables and then query the database with `select * from relation where id in (...);` for design 1 in parallel and for design 2 a similar query but one that also uses the `dependent_var` column. The results were as follows:

1. Both design beat the current system and,
2. Design 2 crushes design 1 performance wise.

**The question**

Now, my question is: does design 2 scale up to a table of size 5000 * 10 million or is there an even better way of doing this?

I appreciate any help!

**Update 1: Create table and select**

Assume `m = 4` and `k = 3`.

For a given dependent variable `y_1` I create an empty table with `create table y1 (id integer, beta double precision, se double precision, pval double precision);`. I then iterate over each file on the disk and populate the database with `psql -d dbname -c "\copy y1 from filepath (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ';', HEADER)"`. Once the data base is populated I create an index with `create index y1_idx on y1 (index)`. The query is `select * from y1 where index in (1, 2, 4834, 56);`

For design 2 I create table `longtable` which has the same columns as `y1` above with the addition of column `dependent_var text`. I proceed to populate the database with the `copy` command from above, replacing `y1` with `longtable`. Once I'm done populating the table I create an index with `create index longtable_idx on longtable (index, dependent_var);`. The query is `select * from longtable where ((index in (1, 2, 4834, 56)) and (dependent_var in ('y_1', 'y_2', 'y_99')));`

Comment: What were those `CREATE TABLE` and `SELECT` statements again?

Comment: I updated my question with the information you asked for.

Comment: Bear in mind that a B-Tree index has approx `O(log(n))` complexity, so Log2 of 50 bln is only 35, therefore not that many lookups. Sure, store it one table, as long as you have a good index why not? You do need to be able to store that much info, back of the envelope says `double` and `bigint` are 8 bytes so you need about 7 terabytes.

Comment: @Charlieface True in theory, but the base of the logarithm is so large that for all practical purposes, the expense of an index scan is independent of the table size.

Answer (score 1):

The two queries don't really match: the one on the large table should have `WHERE dependent_var ='y_1'` rather than an `IN` list.

Anyway, the large table is often the better way if all the files have the same column structure. You could have a two-column index on `(dependent_var, "index')` or, if you need `IN` lists for both, two individual indexes for the columns.

One reason to consider the first solution would be if you regularly need to remove the data for a whole file. In that case I recommend a partitioned table with one partition per file. That would also save you the index on `dependent_var`.

What is better depends on the details of your requirements; I find it hard to make a generic recommendation.